# Query to find and average weighted price for day trades

Tags: sql, sql-server, finance, stocks

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740489/query-to-find-an-average-weighted-price) old question which brings a nice approach for calculating weighted average prices. It basically consists in grouping by the stock name and then fetching the sum(quantity*price)/sum(quantity)

But in day trades you buy and sell the asset in the same day, meaning that the final quantity of the day is zero and sql returns: `Divide by zero error encountered`

A examples would be

3 trades for the same stock

```
 1. Price 10 Quantity 
 2. 100 Price 8 Quantity 100
 3. Price 30 Quantity 200
```

Do you guys know some workaround ? Is there a way to group trades with positive and negative quantities separately ?

Comment: Most likely. But with no more details than you posted that is about as close as we can get.

Comment: use a `case` statement inside 2 seperate `sum()` statements `SUM(case when qty >0 then qty*price_per else 0 END)` type idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure, add a grouping bucket defined by the sign of the amount...

```
Select assetIdentifier, 
    case when amount > 0 then 'debit' else 'credit' end typeTx, 
     Avg(Amount) 
from table
group by assetIdentifier,
   case when amount > 0 then 'debit' else 'credit' end
```

or, if you want both values on a single output row,

```
Select assetIdentifier, 
    avg(case when amount > 0 then amount end) debit , 
    avg(case when amount < 0 then amount end) credit
from table
group by assetIdentifier
```

Answer (score 1):

The formula for the weighted average is:

```
sum(quantity*price)/sum(quantity)
------------------------^ NOT price
```

If you want to ignore the direction of the trade, then just use absolute value:

```
sum(abs(quantity)*price)/sum(abs(quantity))
```